# Convert text files recursively to UTF-8 in PowerShell

Tags: windows-7, conversion, powershell

I have a folder with text files which includes other folders in it, and these also contain some text files. I need to recursively convert all these files to UTF-8 encoding in PowerShell and preserve the folder structure during this process. I have tried this:

```
foreach( $i in get-childitem -recurse -name ) {
    get-content $i | out-file -encoding utf8 -filepath some_folder/$i
}
```

But it doesn't work, it can't reproduce the hierarchy of folders. How do I cope with this problem?

Comment: Which version of PowerShell is this? In the one that came with (my copy of) Win7 (v2?), there's `Get-ChildItem` but not `Get-Children`...

Comment: It was a misspelling, I've corrected it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this one.

```
foreach($i in Get-ChildItem -Recurse) {
    if ($i.PSIsContainer) {
        continue
    }

    $dest = $i.Fullname.Replace($PWD, "some_folder")
    if (!(Test-Path $(Split-Path $dest -Parent))) {
        New-Item $(Split-Path $dest -Parent) -type Directory
    }

    get-content $i | out-file -encoding utf8 -filepath $dest
}
```

It grabs the full path of the file and replaces the current directory with the one you want. For example, you run this command in the directory `C:\1\` (`$PWD = C:\1\`). If it finds the file `C:\1\2\file.txt`, it'll give you a `$dest` of `some_folder\2\file.txt`.

The first if block is there so you don't try to convert a directory.

The directories have to be created if they don't already exist - I originally forgot that.

---

If you want UTF8 without BOM, replace the `get-content $i | out-file -encoding utf8 -filepath $dest` line with the following ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5596984/1030702)):

```
$filecontents = Get-Content $i
$Utf8NoBomEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding($False)
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($i, $filecontents, $Utf8NoBomEncoding)
```

Note that this may not be very performant for larger files, since it reads entire files into memory before writing them again. If efficiency is needed, it is possible to read line by line, or even a specific number of bytes at a time. However, I'd rather just write a quick program in C# by that point (since you'd be using .NET fuctions in PS anyway).

Comment: It does not work for me. It says there is an error in line 6 ($dest etc...). It tries to call a method with a NULL argument and its wrong.

Comment: I haven't used PowerShell enough, apparently.. the quotes were not necessary. And the directories must be created if they don't already exist. I've edited it to fix that, and actually tested it this time (more than just echoing the paths). Not sure how you got that error, though, what did you replace `some_folder` with?

Comment: @Roman, You need to define $PWD, else $PWD is NULL. 
If your files are stored in "X:\txt_Files" and you want to store the converted files in "X:\UTF_Files", then add:
$PWD = "X:\txt_Files"
and replace "some_folder" with "X:\UTF_Files"

Comment: @Martin `$PWD` is supposed to automatically refer to the current working directory. `"some_folder"` does have to be replaced with the appropriate folder.

Comment: @Bob It worked as expected, except the fact it throws some errors about some files that don't exists, because it tries to find the file on a invalid location. 
What if I want to convert files to UTF-8 without BOM? What do I have to add to this script?

Comment: @darksoulsong You'll have to clarify what you mean by invalid location, though it should be possible to add a check to prevent visible errors. As for no BOM, replace the `out-file` stuff (basically, what's after `get-content $i | `) with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5596984)

Comment: @Bob Thx Bob. Sry, but I have no xp with PSHELL scripting, so I think I'm missing something. I tried those solutions and it didn't works. I've put [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($MyPath, $dest, $Utf8NoBomEncoding) and an error complayning about the pipe showed up. If I remove the pipe, the script runs but another error occurs: it says "$MyPath" is null. And if I use "$i" instead of "$MyPath" it creates the folders only, inside "some_folder". If you got the time, you could update your answer with a "WITHOUT BOM" solution. What do you think? =)

Comment: @darksoulsong whoops, my mistake - that function doesn't take a pipe. updated (but untested - I don't have access to a Windows machine right now)

Comment: @Bob Thanks! But this time it shows: "Exception on calling 'WritingAllLines' with 3 parameters: 'Value can't be null'".
About the invalid location I told you, PowerShell complains about Get-Content. It says that the current file doesn't exists. In fact the file path is incorrect, it is trying to find the file in the root directory, that is, where I saved the .ps1 file. Maybe I should  include the full path but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

- Allows for files and folders
- File extension agnostic
- Overwrites original file if destination equals the path
- Encoding as a parameter

Usage: &"TextEncoding.ps1" -path "c:\windows\temps\folder1" -encoding "UTF8"

Here is the script I created:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(  
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$path,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string]$dest = $path,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$encoding
)

function Set-Encoding(){

    #ensure it is a valid path
    if(-not(Test-Path -Path $path)){

        throw "File or directory not found at {0}" -f $path
    }

    #if the path is a file, else a directory
    if(Test-Path $path -PathType Leaf){

        #if the provided path equals the destination
        if($path -eq $dest){

            #get file extension
            $ext = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($path)

            #create destination
            $dest = $path.Replace([System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($path), ("temp_encoded{0}" -f $ext))

            #output to file with encoding
            Get-Content $path | Out-File -FilePath $dest -Encoding $encoding -Force

            #copy item to original path to overwrite (note move-item loses encoding)
            Copy-Item -Path $dest -Destination $path -Force -PassThru | ForEach-Object { Write-Output -inputobject ("{0} encoded {1}" -f $encoding, $_) }

            #remove the extra file
            Remove-Item $dest   

        }else{

            #output to file with encoding
            Get-Content $path | Out-File -FilePath $dest -Encoding $encoding -Force     

        }

    }else{

        #get all the files recursively
        foreach($i in Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse) {


            if ($i.PSIsContainer) {
                continue
            }

            #get file extension
            $ext = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($i)

            #create destination
            $dest = "$path\temp_encoded{0}" -f $ext

            #output to file with encoding
            Get-Content $i.FullName | Out-File -FilePath $dest -Encoding $encoding -Force

            #copy item to original path to overwrite (note move-item loses encoding)
            Copy-Item -Path $dest -Destination $i.FullName -Force -PassThru | ForEach-Object { Write-Output -inputobject ("{0} encoded {1}" -f $encoding, $_) }

            #remove the extra file
            Remove-Item $dest

        }

    }

}

Set-Encoding
```

Comment: /TextEncoding.ps1 : File .\enc.ps1 cannot be loaded because running
cripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
ttp://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
t line:1 char:1
 ./TextEncoding..ps1 -path "...\app\models"  ...
 ~~~~~~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

Comment: ok, but if I have a Folder with 1000 .txt files. What will be the code as too convert them all to UTF-8 ?

Comment: hmm... it converted all files regardless of their file type. So I got *converted* gif, jpeg, etc...., too. They would be destroyed if I had no backup

Answer (score 0):

I had to modify script found over here a bit, to run it on my W10/PS 5.1

```
Get-ChildItem -Include *.php -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $file = $_.FullName

    $mustReWrite = $false
    # Try to read as UTF-8 first and throw an exception if
    # invalid-as-UTF-8 bytes are encountered.
    try
    {
        [IO.File]::ReadAllText($file,[Text.Utf8Encoding]::new($false, $true))
    }
    catch [System.Text.DecoderFallbackException]
    {
        # Fall back to Windows-1250
        $content = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($file,[Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1250))
        $mustReWrite = $true
    }

    # Rewrite as UTF-8 without BOM (the .NET frameworks' default)
    if ($mustReWrite)
    {
        Write "Converting from 1250 to UTF-8"
        [IO.File]::WriteAllText($file, $content)
    }
    else
    {
        Write "Already UTF-8-encoded"
    } }
```

Comment: Code without any explanation is useless. Can you elaborate on this a little more?

Comment: The code opens recursively *.php files, foreaches them through file object.. Firstly, tries to open it using .NET  function read its content, using 2nd parameter of ReadAllText() for utf8 encoding. If it doesn't throw exception, means the file is already in UTF, and we're done for this file. Otherwise, opens it in the other encoding, we are looking for (and want to convert from). According the success or exception on the try, if the second is true, we simply write the content in target utf8 encoding over the original file.